# Jenkins : migrate groovy scripts from old Warnings plugin to Warnings Next Generation Plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

I wrote a lot of groovy scripts for the old warning plugin of Jenkins. But now I'm using the Warning NG plugin.
And my groovy scripts are no more compatible.

Could you help me to update them as currently, main package no more exists :

```
import hudson.plugins.warnings.parser.Warning
import hudson.plugins.analysis.util.model.Priority

String warningTxt= matcher.group(1)
String objName= matcher.group(2)
String prjName= matcher.group(3)
return new Warning(prjName+"\\"+objName, 0, "Synergy update warning", warningTxt, "", Priority.HIGH)
```

hudson.plugins.warnings.parser.Warning and hudson.plugins.analysis.util.model.Priority packages no more exists. Are they replaced by other packages ?

thanks a lot.

Comment: problem resolved, i didn't rememeber that I already did the conversion years ago :

Answer (score 1):

problem resolved, i didn't rememeber that I already did the conversion years ago :

```
import edu.hm.hafner.analysis.Severity

String line = 0
String column = 0
String warningTxt= matcher.group(1)
String objName= matcher.group(2)
String prjName= matcher.group(3)

builder.setFileName(prjName+"\\"+objName)
.setLineStart(Integer.parseInt(line))
.setColumnStart(Integer.parseInt(column))
.setCategory(warningTxt)
.setType("Synergy update warning")
.setMessage("")
.setSeverity(Severity.WARNING_NORMAL)

return builder.build()
```

but I now have an error (that I didn't have years ago) :

An exception occurred during evaluation of the Groovy script: edu.hm.hafner.analysis.Issue cannot be cast to java.util.Optional

Comment: Same boat as you :)   From the contextual Jenkins help, jenkins recommend the return as follows: `return builder.buildOptional();`